# SQL Function That Takes A Table and Column List as Parameters

Tags: sql-server, function, constraints

I have a database with a number of mapping tables.

Each of the mapping tables contains a group of key columns, a mapped value, and a date range when the mapping is applicable.

For instance

```
mappingtable_a (
  acol,
  bcol,
  ccol,
  mapped,
  startdate,
  enddate
)
```

I might use this in the following way

```
select
  a.acol,
  a.bcol,
  a.ccol,
  m.mapped
from
  atable a left join
  mappingtable_a m on (
    a.acol = m.acol and
    a.bcol = m.bcol and
    a.ccol = m.ccol and
    a.adate >= m.startdate and
    a.adate <= m.enddate
  )
```

I want to enforce a constraint check on these tables, to make sure there is never any overlap in date ranges for the combination of mapping columns.

This seems fairly straight forward for a single table, if I created a constraint check function specific to each table the constraint is on.

```
function checkrange_mappingtable_a(
  acol_value,
  bcol_value,
  ccol_value,
  startdate_value,
  enddate_value
) {
  --find all date ranges for this combination in mappingtable_a
  --verify the new range doesn't overlap
}
```

I'm wondering if I can create a function that would handle all of my mapping tables, rather than individually.

Something like

```
function checkrange (
  thetable,
  columnlist,
  valuelist,
  startdate_value,
  enddate_value
) {
  --find all date ranges in thetable where columnlist=valuelist
  --verify the new range doesn't overlap
}
```

Which would could then be passed something like this for `mappingtable_a`.

```
checkrange(
  'mappingtable_a',
  ['acol','bcol','ccol'],
  [acol_value,bcol_value,ccol_value],
  startdate_value,
  enddate_value
)
```

Am I on a decent path here? I'd prefer to go this route as it would eliminate the need to create a function for each table.

Comment: It is good, when trying to JOIN use Cross JOIN to allow you to use your function when using JOIN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/cross-join

Comment: I'm more concerned with inserts and updates to the mapping tables. On update/insert, I need to validate that the new values don't overlap with the old. I only ever want one row from the table on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're not going to be able to make a function that generically handles multiple tables because that would require dynamic sql, and dynamic sql is not allowed in user defined functions.

**Alternative idea**:  Put all of your mapping date ranges in one table.  Since the adjoining tables might not always have the same number of key columns, this means that some mappings would have NULLs in some key columns, but you would ignore those columns in the JOINs for that table anyway.  You'd also have to add a TableName column to the mapping table to keep the TableA/ColumnA mapping separate from the TableB/ColumnA mapping, but I don't see that as a big deal.

So you would have your date-range constraint in one single table, and you could join any table to it like this:

```
select
  a.acol,
  a.bcol,
  a.ccol,
  m.mapped
from
  atable a left join
  mappingtable m on (
    m.TableName = 'atable' and
    a.acol = m.acol and
    a.bcol = m.bcol and
    a.ccol = m.ccol and
    a.adate >= m.startdate and
    a.adate <= m.enddate
  )
```

Comment: Any other options for this situation? Or just write the ~same function for every mapping table.